# Installing Mongo db 4 CentOS 6.1 fails

Tags: mongodb

I am running  CentOS 6.1 -

```
# lsb_release -d  
Description:    CentOS release 6.10 (Final)
```

release ver  is   6 -

```
# python -c 'import yum, pprint; yb = yum.YumBase(); pprint.pprint(yb.conf.yumvar, width=1)'
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
{'arch': 'ia32e',
 'basearch': 'x86_64',
 'infra': 'stock',
 'releasever': '6',
 'uuid': 'af2ec701-1921-42b0-95b1-4ec3ba0f92b7'}
```

relository -

```
# cat /etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb-org-4.0.repo
[mongodb-org-4.0]
name=MongoDB Repository
baseurl=https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/redhat/$releasever/mongodb-org/4.0/x86_64/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
gpgkey=https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-4.0.asc
```

Run  update

```
yum  update
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Setting up Update Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: ftp.cvut.cz
 * epel: mirrors.nic.cz
 * extras: ftp.cvut.cz
 * updates: ftp.cvut.cz
No Packages marked for Update
```

From  https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat/    I  run  -

```
# yum install -y mongodb-org
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.karneval.cz
 * epel: mirrors.nic.cz
 * extras: mirror.karneval.cz
 * updates: mirror.karneval.cz
No package mongodb-org available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/redhat/6/mongodb-org/4.0/x86_64/    exists

So  why does it  fail ?

Thanks

Comment: did you perform `yum update` after adding repo to sources ?

Comment: Yes  and I updated  my question

Comment: try `yum clean all ` then update again. possibly cleaning cache
(If repo is added successfully then `yum update` must download metadata for that repo.)

Comment: were you able to install ?

Comment: did that  but to no avail.  Got  'No Packages marked for Update'

Comment: Solved it  by  directly  downloading  .rpm  packages   for   RHEL 6.2     I am  assuming  these  are  compatible  with CentOS 6.10    Stil not  sure  why  repo  did not work